# how to recover data from a OSX/Bootcamp HDD with two Windows partitions and broken boot record to a new HDD?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, boot-camp, bootrepair

I have an HDD which doesn't boot ([details](https://superuser.com/questions/659835/windows-failed-to-start-0xc00000e-for-os-x-dual-partition-windows-7-disk)) but when mounted into USB enclosure, all files are completely readable. I have a spare larger clean HDD which I can clean install / repair to.

**What is the best way to recover data, programs and settings to a new HDD?**

The original HDD has Mountain Lion OS X and dual-partition Windows 7 (system + data), installed via [this scheme](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16138143#16138143).

Comment: 13 hours ago you said all your partitions are readable in Wnidows.  You can recover the data easy enough.  Your programs likely should just be reinstalled.

Comment: @Ramhound Manually copying files is an obvious solution. The question is whether there's a way to also reliably recover programs installed and their settings--and to avoid manual reinstall.

Comment: You can create a image of the partition then restore the partition on a new hdd after you have setup a working boot sector.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you detail how is it better to do that: which way to create a partition, to setup a working boot sector, to properly restore the image to new HDD?