# Cannot boot into Mac OS X after partitioning in Windows

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, boot-camp, windows-8.1

My Mac is a Macbook Pro 17", I got it from my friend (no original disc).

So after upgrading it to Mavericks (I was unable to install Windows using Boot camp of 10.6.8), Boot Camp successfully let me install Windows 8.1 Pro (x64).

However, after installing, whenever I install the Software Support in Windows, Windows always show Blue screen after showing the logo. I was able to restore Windows back. Therefore, I am now using Windows with only basic components, no Boot Camp driver.

The problem is that, I shrink the Boot Camp partition, and create another NTFS partition (so I can store data in the second partition as I usually do when using Windows). Now, I cannot boot into Mac OS anymore. Holding Command + Option + R does nothing, holding Option while startup shows a hard drive named Windows (instead of Mac HD).

Can I make the Mac bootable again? Beside shrinking the Bootcamp partition, I didn't touch any of the other partition. And if possible, is there any available driver for Windows 8.1?

Comment: It sounds like your problem has the same cause as the one asked [in this question.](http://superuser.com/questions/659835/windows-failed-to-start-0xc00000e-for-os-x-dual-partition-windows-7-disk) Please read the link on hybrid MBRs in my answer to that question and then check your disk for GPT/MBR consistency.

Comment: @RodSmith I can only boot into Windows now, how can I check the consistency? (but I guess it is not, because I used Windows Disk Management to change the partition) And if data is not my concern, is there anyway to merge everything into a completely one partition as Mac originally be?

Comment: [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) is available for Windows, OS X, and Linux, so you can use it in any of those environments. If you need to do anything that `gdisk` can't handle (like resize a filesystem), you may need to use an emergency disk, such as [System Rescue CD.](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)